# Data is not sent using axios to backend in react and Unsupported protocol localhost: axoos is thrown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mern

I am using express js as backend and also have added proxy of backend in the package.json of react js. Before it used to throw an error with fetch method and moved to the axios method to prevent that. The data is in json format and completely working after copy pasting on postman to check backend.

```
import React ,{useState} from 'react'
import './contact.css'
import axios from "axios"


const Contact = (e) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [description,setDescription]=useState('');
    const[message,setMessage]=useState('')

const [name ,setName] = useState('')


const url='localhost:5000/api/contact'
    const contactClick=async (e)=>{
      const subject="contacting"
        e.preventDefault();
      const formData={
        name:name,
        email:email,
        subject:subject,
        description:description
      }

      console.log(JSON.stringify(formData));
      axios.post(url, JSON.stringify(formData))
   .then(res => setMessage('email sent'))
   .catch(err => {setMessage('Unable to sent email ')
  return console.log(err)})

    };
    
  return (
    <>
    <div className='form__container' >
    <form onSubmit={contactClick} className='contact__form'>
    {message}

        <input type="email" placeholder='Email' value={email} required onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value) 
} />


        <input type="text"  placeholder='name' value={name} required onChange={e=>setName(e.target.value)} />
        <input type="textarea" placeholder='Description' className='text-area' value={description} onChange={(e)=>setDescription(e.target.value)}/>
        <input type="submit" title="Submit" />

    </form>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Contact
```

[image: error thrown while submitting]

Comment: Mostly a guess but, why the use of `JSON.stringify`?  Isn't axios just expecting the object, not a string?

Comment: Changed that to object but its not working error is same as before

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? What error were you getting? fetch should just work, replacing with axios should be unnecessary. If I had to guess I'd say CORS but without more information I can't really tell what's going on. What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: So you actually have a folder named `localhost:5000` inside the current folder? No? Then why did you specify a _relative_ URL?

Comment: The error above is specifying that your URI is invalid. You need to put http:// in front of localhost. It thinks localhost is your protocol because it hasn't been told what protocol to use to connect to localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `axios.post()` takes data as object not string as mentioned here in the docs.

replace it with `axios.post(url, formData)` without stringifying it.

https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example

But the resulted data from `JSON.stringify(formData)` is `'{the data}'`

Comment: I have added image of the error after changing it back to object and passing it in axios.

Comment: change the url to `const url='http://localhost:5000/api/contact'`

Answer (score 25):

> Unsupported protocol: localhost

Because the URL you're using has `localhost` as a protocol:

```
const url='localhost:5000/api/contact'
```

Compare this to a "complete" URL:

```
const url='http://localhost:5000/api/contact'
```

The URL starts with a protocol and a colon.  Whatever is parsing that URL isn't going to intuitively know what you meant, it's just going to parse the string you provided based on standards.

Either specify the protocol:

```
const url='http://localhost:5000/api/contact'
```

Or omit it but keep the `//` root to use whatever protocol the current page is using:

```
const url='//localhost:5000/api/contact'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it may be cors policy blocking to be sent to backend from localhost:3000 to localhost:5000